# Kafka Wheel Timer

Tags: scala, timer, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Good Day,

I would like to find out if kafka queue can hold data for a few seconds and than release data.

I receive a message from a kafka topic, 
After parsing the data, I hold it in memory for some time (10 seconds) (This builds up as unique messages come through), with each message having it's own timer), I want kafka to tell me that that message has expired (10 seconds) so that i can continue with other tasks.

But since flink/kafka is event driven, I was hoping kafka has some sort of round timing wheel that can reproduce the key for a message after 10 seconds to the consumer.

Any idea on how I can archieve this using flink windowing or kafka features?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your initial problem:

> I would like to find out if kafka queue can hold data for a few seconds and than release data

You can set up `log.cleanup.policy` as `delete` (this is the default) and change the `retention.ms` from the default `604800000` (1 week) to `10000`.

Can you explain again what else you want to check, and what did you mean after the `Regards` part?

Comment: I think by `hold` Ideas frontier means to postpone forwarding the data, not removing them from the broker.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i need @wardziniak

Answer (score 0):

You could look closer to Kafka Streams library. https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html, https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html.

Using Kafka Streams you can do lot of complex event processing work. Processor API is lower level API and gives you more flexibility, ex Each processing message put in state store (Kafka Streams abstraction, that is replicated to changelog topic) and then  with the `Punctuator` you can check if message *expired*.

Comment: Thanks looking into these suggestions